# How to compute correlation between columns of matrix A with columns of matrix B?

Tags: matlab

Given two matrices `A` and `B`, How can I compute correlation between columns of A with columns of B in matlab?
`corr()` function support the vector form, but not matrices.

Comment: xcorr or xcorr2 will not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you want [`corr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html) or you can use

```
A = randn(5,3);

B = randn(5,3);

C =corrcoef([A B], 'rows','complete'); 

C=C(size(A,1)+1:end,1:size(A,2)+1)
```

Comment: What is "rows" and "complete" stands for ?

Comment: @user2806363 consider reading the documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri, what does  each value means? If we compute correlation between corresponding columns of A with B (column 1 of A with column 1 of B), then we would end up with three correlation values.